# Why are there rectangle shaped glitches when using motion blur problem in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm creating an animation for a client and am getting rectangle shaped glitches in my renders when motion blur is on.

I've tried fiddling with various settings to no avail.
Any suggestions ( not using motion blur is not an answer BTW! )

[image]

Comment: using blender 2.75 BTW

Comment: Are you rendering on GPU?

Comment: did you try using composting to get the motion blur effect instead ?

Comment: I'm using CPU. Comping motion blur does not look the same, and doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: I found I that it is the stones on the ground that are the "problem" , they are particles , if they are disabled, or if I uncheck the motion blur just for the them the glitches disappear. Its a bug I think.

Comment: If it's repeatable, it'll likely get solved quickly if you report it to the bug tracker.

Comment: Are you using Bilateral Blur in the compositor by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, not a settings issue or user error. Go ahead and report it in the [bugtracker](https://developer.blender.org/). (Though it's probably been fixed since 2.75)

Comment: I came through this question accidentally, I found a similar problem in a tutorial about Passes, where he had this issue and explained why and how to fix.
This might be due to using Bilateral Blur filter in the compositor, for a pass to remove noise or/and fireflies, if a pixel has a huge color data, Bilateral Blur filter will maximize this pixel to become a rectangle, the solution is to go through a Math node with (Greater Than) factor to get the values down, check the video at 51:30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq5YWSpvME8

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was not due to using the Bilateral Blur filter or any passes. I think it is a Bug.